# Unable to connect to Amazon RDS instance

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, amazon-rds, oracle-sql-developer

I recently created an oracle instance on Amazon RDS. Unfortunately, I'm not able to connect to the instance using Oracle SQL Developer.

The (relevant) information I have from Amazon;

Endpoint - The DNS address of the DB Instance: xxx.yyy.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

DB Name - The definition of the term Database Name depends on the database engine in use. For the MySQL database engine, the Database Name is the name of a database hosted in your Amazon DB Instance. An Amazon DB Instance can host multiple databases. Databases hosted by the same DB Instance must have a unique name within that instance. For the Oracle database engine, Database Name is used to set the value of ORACLE_SID, which must be supplied when connecting to the Oracle RDS instance: ZZZ

Master Username - Name of master user for your DB Instance: org

Port - Port number on which the database accepts connections: 1521

From this information, the connection settings in SQL Developer are pretty obvious, so I don't really see what I could be missing...

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by opening the "Firewall" under Security Groups in the AWS Dashboard to incoming connections from my computer's IP.